# calculate difference between consecutive numbers in different rows of a field in the same model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I am trying to calculate the difference between consecutive numeric values in the odometer_reading field of my model.
My **Models.py** has fields like below:

```py
class Refuel(models.Model):
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    gaz_station = models.ForeignKey(
        GazStation, related_name=_("Station"), blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
    odometer_reading = models.PositiveIntegerField(_("Compteur KM"), blank=True, null=True)
    snitch = models.PositiveIntegerField(_("Mouchard KM"), blank=True, null=True)
    fuel_quantity = models.DecimalField(_("Quantitée en Litres"), max_digits=5, decimal_places=1)
    fuel_unit_price = models.DecimalField(_("Prix en DH"), max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    note = models.CharField(_("Remarque"), max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(_("Created at"), auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(_("Updated at"), auto_now=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    @property
    def total_price(self):
        total_price = self.fuel_quantity * self.fuel_unit_price
        return total_price

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["gaz_station", "-created_at"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.vehicle.serie
```

I want to use a **CBV** to get the distance between every two refuel for the same vehicle so I can calculate fuel consumption per km.
is there a way to do it?
**EDITED:**
I want to return with every refuel the fuel consumption per km using the precedent refuel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm Using the form_valid `**RefuelCreatView**` when validation the new record to get the oldest data and perform my calculation and store the **RefuelConsumption** Model.

```py
class RefuelCreationView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Refuel
    form_class = RefuelCreationForm
    template_name = "refuel/refuel_form.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("refuel:controlor-refuel-list")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user_id = self.request.user.id
        form.instance.gaz_station = GazStation.objects.get(Controlor_id=self.request.user.id)
        old_refuel_data = Refuel.objects.order_by().distinct("vehicle")
        for refuel in old_refuel_data:
            if refuel.vehicle == form.instance.vehicle and form.instance.odometer_reading:
                consumption = (refuel.fuel_quantity / (form.instance.odometer_reading - refuel.odometer_reading)) * 100
                FuelConsumption.objects.create(
                    vehicle=refuel.vehicle,
                    gaz_station=form.instance.gaz_station,
                    Controlor_id=self.request.user,
                    driver=refuel.vehicle.driver,
                    consumption=consumption,
                    is_active=True,
                )
            elif refuel.vehicle == form.instance.vehicle and form.instance.snitch:
                consumption = (refuel.fuel_quantity / (form.instance.snitch - refuel.snitch)) * 100
                FuelConsumption.objects.create(
                    vehicle=refuel.vehicle,
                    gaz_station=form.instance.gaz_station,
                    Controlor_id=self.request.user,
                    driver=refuel.vehicle.driver,
                    consumption=consumption,
                    is_active=True,
                )
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Refuel.objects.select_related("vehicle__gaz_station__Controlor_id").filter(
            vehicle__gaz_station__Controlor_id=self.request.user
        )
```

and this work very well. I don't know if it's respecting the best practices in programming or not, I'm open to any advise.

Comment: For a start, you could probably just use `Refuel.objects.filter(vehicle=form.instance.vehicle).order_by('-created_at')`

Answer (score 1):

In your views you can create a view function that pulls two refuel objects then you can take the difference and use it as your templates context. You then can access it in the template using whatever you call it in this example we just used the same name as the variable "difference".

```
from myapp.models import Refuel 
from django.template import loader
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def odometer_difference(request):
    # get the two refuel objects with the odometer readings you needed to compare 
    refuel_1 = Refuel.objects.filter('your_filter') 
    refuel_2 = Refuel.objects.filter('your_filter')

    #define template 
    template = loader.get_template('my_template.html')
    
    difference = refuel_2.odometer_reading - refuel_1.odometer_reading

    context = { 'difference':difference} 

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this will gives me what I want but I don't think is the best way if I work on thousands of valus with hundreds valus for every vehicle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`Window`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions) functions that uses [**`Lag`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#lag) to get a previous row's value like this:

```
from django.db.models import Window
from django.db.models.functions import Lag

last_odometer_reading = Window(
    expression=Lag('odometer_reading', default=0),
    partition_by=F('vehicle')
    order_by=F('created_at').asc(),
)

Refuel.objects.annotate(
    last_odometer_reading=last_odometer_reading
).annotate(
    odometer_difference=F('odometer_reading') - F('last_odometer_reading')
)
```

Each refuel row will be annotated with the last odometer reading (based on the refuel of the same vehicle) and will also be annotated with the difference between the current reading and the last reading.

Comment: I used the **CreatView** for the Refuel to perform the consumption calculation in the `form_valid` method and store the information before saving the new *Refuel* record. you can see the View and I hope you can give your advise about it.